# Two main router-outlets with different layouts

Tags: angular, routes, router, outlet

[Layout for all users](http://imgur.com/a/5DEex)

[Layout for personnel (like admin control panel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5NNG.jpg)

I have one `router-outlet` which has first layout. At `/personnel` I'd like to use the second one. How to do that? I don't want to hide elements because `personnel` has also it's components like `personnel/users` etc.

I'd like to load `personnel` as independent component which is not inside main `router-outlet`. `personnel` should have it's own `router-outlet`.

Let's make it a bit more clear.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { // first layout (here is the first and for now the only one router-outlet
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: SiteComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'install', component: InstallationComponent, canActivate: [ InstallationAuth ] },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [ LoginAuth ] },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'reset', component: ResetComponent, canActivate: [ LoginAuth ] }
    ]
  },
  { //second layout (personnel should have it's own router-outlet
    path: 'personnel',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: PersonnelComponent, canActivate: [ PersonnelAuth ]},
      { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, outlet: 'personnel' }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your rout hierarchy one step down, So in your root app component define single `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` without any layout, in one step down define your default empty route component with your main layout

```
<...LayoutMain>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<...LayoutMain>`
```

in secon component define your personnel Layout whit /personnel root

```
  <...Layoutpersonnel >
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <...Layoutpersonnel >`
```